# Matplotlib error, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex': 'latex'?

Tags: matplotlib

When I try running the very simple code snippet from www.matplotlib.org,

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
## for Palatino and other serif fonts use:
#rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Example data
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{time} (s)')
plt.ylabel(r'\textit{voltage} (mV)',fontsize=16)
plt.title(r"\TeX\ is Number "
          r"$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
          fontsize=16, color='gray')
# Make room for the ridiculously large title.
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

plt.savefig('tex_demo')
plt.show()
```

This is highly unusual this code has worked for me before and I cannot figure out what the issue is. The error message that I receive is enormous and shown below. Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Thanks!!

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py",
>   line 332, in **call**
>       return printer(obj)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py",
>   line 237, in 
>       png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py",
>   line 121, in print_figure
>       fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 2216, in print_figure
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
>   line 507, in print_png
>       FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
>   line 430, in draw
>       self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py",
>   line 55, in draw_wrapper
>       return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py",
>   line 1299, in draw
>       renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py",
>   line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
>       a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py",
>   line 55, in draw_wrapper
>       return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
>   line 2437, in draw
>       mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py",
>   line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
>       a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py",
>   line 55, in draw_wrapper
>       return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py",
>   line 1135, in draw
>       renderer)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py",
>   line 1075, in _get_tick_bboxes
>       extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py",
>   line 933, in get_window_extent
>       bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py",
>   line 308, in _get_layout
>       ismath=False)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
>   line 226, in get_text_width_height_descent
>       s, fontsize, renderer=self)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py",
>   line 602, in get_text_width_height_descent
>       dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
>
> File
>   "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py",
>   line 393, in make_dvi
>       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>
> File "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336,
>   in check_output
>       **kwargs).stdout
>
> File "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403,
>   in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>
> File "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709,
>   in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "/Users/evan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344,
>   in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex':
>   'latex'

Comment: What did you change in between? The error suggests you do not have latex or that latex cannot be found. So maybe it is not in your path any more?

Comment: I really don't know, I cannot find the issue..

Comment: The comment was meant for you to check if latex is in your path.

Comment: Did adding the path to the LaTeX binary solve this?

Comment: No - this was several months ago but if I am not mistaken I just had to comment the line of code referencing TeX out.

Comment: Maybe you did not install LaTeX on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

For linux:

```
 sudo yum install latex
 sudo yum install dvipng
```

For Window:
install texlive.

ref. https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/usetex.html?highlight=latex

Answer (score 0):

Download miktex and add the path in environment variables for Windows.